# How to get Main impression in search console via search console api?

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

According to [some security reason](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1308626?hl=en-GB&utm_id=ad#Queries), Google doesn't let us see all of the impression, and if you sum numbers in impression in search console API, always it smaller than that number you see in search console panel.

Now my question is " How can get this number in search console API ?"

is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some project, we tried this already. some differences exist between search console and search console API

if you [try explorer](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query) you notice

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the top level metrics (no queries, no landing pages, no filter by country or device), you can get "total impressions" by sending a request without the dimension key and the date range you prefer (3 months if you want to emulate the UI)

Here is an example for 1 month worth of data for top-level metrics:

```
 let body = {
    siteUrl: "https://yourwebsite.com",
    requestBody: {
      startDate: "2021-01-01",
      endDate: "2021-01-31",
    }
}
```